# How to insert AJAX textarea

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Hi I'm having trouble in inserting textarea for ajax PLease help me to figure out whats wrong. Thank you

```
      $('#submit').click(function(){
         var message_options     =  $('#message_options').val();         

         $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: ajax_params.ajax_url,
                data: {"action": "data", 
                "message_options":message_options,
         },
                success: function(data){
          }
        });  
      });
```

PHP functions:

```
      function data(){
      global $wpdb;
      $message_options = $_POST['message_options'];

                 $result2 =  $wpdb->insert( $table_client_event_details , 
                   array( 
                     'contact_person_id'=>$wpdb->insert_id,
                     'message_options'=> $message_options,
                    )
                 );
      }
```

Comment: r u getting the value in `print_r($_POST)` in PHP? plz chk

Comment: you have to define as :  global $wpdb after check it.

Comment: hi devpro yes there is value

Comment: than where is it? `$wpdb` u didnt define yet?

Comment: hi @ Mansukh Khandhar  yes I already include global $wpdb

Comment: `global $wpdb;` inside your `data()` function, before this line `$message_options = $_POST['message_options'];` and test

Comment: Ok I try this.. get back to you once done

Comment: Is anything returned inside ajax succes function? Else check your php code on errors.

Comment: hi Lars Mertens ok i will check thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just change this

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){
     var message_options     =  $('textarea').val(); // I change the element id to textarea. I dont know why if I use ID does not working. Thank you

     $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: ajax_params.ajax_url,
            data: {"action": "data", 
            "message_options":message_options,
     },
            success: function(data){
      }
    });  
  });
```